# How to clear a bit in a byte?

Tags: c#, byte, bit-manipulation

I need to **set** and **clear** some bits in bytes of a byte array.

**Set** works good but **clear** doesn't compile (I guess because negation has int as result and it's negative by then and ...).

```
public const byte BIT_1 = 0x01;
public const byte BIT_2 = 0x02;

byte[] bytes = new byte[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

// set 1st bit
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    bytes[i] |= BIT_1;

// clear 2nd bit (set it to 0)
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    bytes[i] &= (~BIT_2);
```

How can I **clear** bits in a byte in a *preferably* simple way ?

Comment: What do you mean by ***"delete"***? Setting it to 0?

Comment: What is C.BIT_1? I see that you have defined a const byte BIT_1, but I can't get what C.BIT_1 is.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios Its a variable.. declared at the top of the code...

Comment: @ChristosPaisios Sorry I copied it from my code and it was declared in a class `C`.

Comment: @mini-me not a problem at all ! I am trying to understnad your code to see if I can help.

Comment: @mini-me The proper term is to **clear**, not to **delete** a bit.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
int i = 0;

// Set 5th bit
i |= 1 << 5;

Console.WriteLine(i); // 32

// Clear 5th bit
i &= ~(1 << 5);

Console.WriteLine(i); // 0
```

Version on bytes (and **on bytes only** in this case):

```
byte b = 0;

// Set 5th bit
b |= 1 << 5;

Console.WriteLine(b);

// Clear 5th bit
b &= byte.MaxValue ^ (1 << 5);

Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Comment: Why not use bitwise not? `~`? What's with the XOR?

Comment: @MatthewWatson `Constant value '-33' cannot be converted to a 'byte'`. XOR is a simple way to remain in positive world, thus allowing to avoid unnecessary casts :)

Comment: @Spook But that only works because you have hard-coded the `5` in the shift. Try replacing that with a variable, and it no longer compiles.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I haven't checked that. It seems to me then, that the only way is to make a double byte-to-int-to-byte cast...

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you can't do this without converting the byte to an int first.

```
byte ClearBit(byte b, int i)
{
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(b);
    x &= ~(1 << i);
    return Convert.ToByte(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be avoided by converting to an `int` and back again:

```
bytes[i] = (byte)(bytes[i] & ~(BIT_2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise operations are not defined on bytes, and using them with bytes [will always return an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079986/why-do-cs-binary-operators-always-return-int-regardless-of-the-format-of-their). So when you use the bitwise NOT on your byte, it will return an int, and as such yield an error when you are trying to AND it with your other byte.

To solve this, you need to explicitely cast the result as a byte again.

```
byte bit = 0x02;
byte x = 0x0;

// set
x |= bit;
Console.WriteLine(x); // 2

// clear
x &= (byte)~bit;
Console.WriteLine(x); // 0
```

Comment: This will technically work, but the code (both OP's and yours) is unclear, because it suggests, that if you set `bit` to 0x03 it will clear 3rd bit, but it won't (at least not how OP would want it to). The core problem - as I understand - is to write code which clears n-th bit, not just a specific one.

Comment: @Spook No, OP’s code does not in any way hint how they would approach the third bit. They could easily set `BIT_3` to `0x04` and everything would be fine.