# "ORing" two bytes together

Tags: c#

I need to take two bytes and OR them together, a rather simple task.  However, I do not know the proper syntax to OR the two bytes together.

```
 byte First = 0x03;
 byte Second = 0x15;

 //Need to or Them
 byte Result = First || Second; //This syntax does not work in C#
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation? You're using the wrong operator. `||` is a *logical* OR. You're looking for `|` which is a bitwise OR.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568216/c-sharp-bitwise-or-needs-casting-with-byte-sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [| Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx)

```
byte Result = (byte)(First | Second);
```

Answer (score -1):

`||` is a logical or not bitwise so you need:

```
byte Result = (byte) (First | Second);
```